# Best way to add remote Ubuntu ARM storage server as drive or folder on remote Ubuntu server?

Tags: server

I have a remote Ubuntu server running plex and I want to connect my remote ARMv71 server as additional storage. I've been searching for a while and I get mixed answers to what the best way is, to accomplish this.

From what I've read there was a debate on SSHFS vs SMB vs NFS. Another guy on the plex Discord suggested OpenVPN and I'm at a loss. My issue is that I can't really find any recent information on what is best for my particular setup. I connect to both servers only using the terminal.

My goal is to **be able to add the storage in Plex's storage manager, so I presume as a browsable folder**. What's the best way to accomplish this?

PS: The Plex server is running 19.04 and the ARM server is running 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Are both remote servers stored locally to each other or at separate, remote locations?

Local to each other: Share the resource via SMB or export it via NFS with appropriate permissions.

Remote to each other: SSHFS works but latency issues abound. SMB/NFS over a VPN would have similar issues.

Alternatively, you could look at installing Plex Media Server on the ARM server. There may be either official and/or unofficial packages available for your architecture. The down side to using separate PMS instances is the devs seem opposed to merging matching libraries from different sources, so you'll need to switch PMS in your client to view all content.

Comment: Both server are stored separately, but by the same provider. I know they're in separate data centers.

The issue with installing it on the ARM server is that the is that it's not powerful enough to handle transcoding. Since I share with other users across different devices, it needs to be able to do that. As far as I know, transcoding might not be possible that architecture.

Comment: Then I'd recommend SSHFS mounts by a user that the PMS can access. Just be prepared for latency and occasional connectivity issues.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll try that and get back.